# Fastest way to filter out all False matrix

Tags: python, numpy, boolean, sparse-matrix

I have numpy boolean matrix which contain about 2,000 slices and it's width, height is 512x512.

```
print(bool_matrix.shape) #(512, 512, 2000)
```

Some slices are all False matrix and I want to filter it out. I have wrote code below but I am wondering if there any faster way to do this?

```
%%timeit
_idx = np.any(bool_matrix, axis=(0,1))
result = np.compress(_idx, bool_matrix, axis=2)
print(result.shape) #(512, 512, 457), filter out 1543 all False matrix

281 ms ± 2.95 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```